# What is the meaning of the girl's words here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Three Teenage girls, Lynda, Laurie & Annie, walking & talking to each other about the college:

> Lynda: Anyway, today in class, in French class, Mr. Leclerc was
> totally flirting with me.

> Annie: (Laughs)

> Laurie: God, here we go!
>
> Lynda: **We were conjugating the verb "to want."**
>
> Laurie: Because he so wants you!
>
> Laurie: Je veuxl Je veuxl

I **bolded** the sentence where I got confused in understanding it.

Is she saying **to want** has so many meanings to it or anything else?

Comment: I suppose he was looking her in the eye when they practiced "I want you". Or Laurie was just teasing her.

Comment: @Max I added more words to my post.

Comment: It was a French class, and they were conjugating the French verb *vouloir*, Englished *to want*. *Je veux* is the present tense first person singular of *voulouir*, and thus the first term in a conjugation.

Comment: @StoneyB please post the answer.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar Does it explain what you needed to know? That's not entirely clear from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *want* does have a variety of meanings. When it is applied a person, it can mean that the person is desired romantically or sexually by another person.

In French class, they were conjugating the verb *vouloir*, which is French for *want*. Lynda construes this as flirting by the teacher, since if the teacher says "I want you" to her (or any other student), it could interpreted as a romantic desire. Laurie thinks this is silly and mocks her by saying "Je veux" (I want).

Answer (score 1):

To [conjugate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conjugate) a verb is

> to list the forms of a verb in a particular order
> normally by person.

In English, want is a regular verb and so is

1st person singular:  I want

2nd person singular:  Thou wantest

3rd person singular:  He/she/it wants.

1st person plural:  We want

2nd person plural:  You want

3rd person plural:  They want

French, however, has many more irregular verbs and so conjugating the verb is a regular practice in French class.